# Download URL content with timeout

Tags: java, urlconnection

I want to download the URL content in java with a specified download time. For ex: i want to have a maximum download timeout of 10 seconds for www.yahoo.com. If download takes more than 10s, then an error should be thrown. I have written the code for opening a connection and downloading the entire contents. But how do i set the download timeout? Here is the code snippet:

```
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        urlconn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlconn.setConnectTimeout(100000);
      //urlconn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        urlconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlconn.connect();
        buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlconn.getInputStream())); 
        while((line = buf.readLine()) != null)
            text.append(line);
        System.out.println(url + "=> "+ urlconn.getResponseCode());
```

Comment: Note that your connect timeout is 100 seconds. You'd like to lower this to 1~3 seconds. @Asaph: no, he's asking for the download (read) timeout.

Comment: @BalusC: Thank you. You're correct. I figured that out shortly before I saw your comment and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it by [`URLConnection#setReadTimeout()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29).

```
urlconn.setReadTimeout(10000); // 10 sec
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I will lower my connecTimeout.

Comment: Does this really set a time limit on the actual reading/downloading? It seems like it's only a limit on the time for readable data to be presented after a connection is established. ["If the timeout expires before there is data available for read, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29) I've tried setting this and then reading in a long jsonarray through an inputstream just like above using a slow connection and the exception was never thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`URLConnection.setReadTimeOut()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29).